# Ninject - Dependency injection across assemblies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have a MVC application that references half a dozen assemblies. Each assembly has dependent components for the web site. And in some case these assemblies have dependencies on one another.
Here is some prototype

```
Assembly1
---------
interface ILogger{...}

Assembly2
--------
class MyLogger : ILogger {...}

Assembly3
--------
interface IRepository {.....}

Assembly4
---------
interface MyResository : IRepository
{
 [Inject]
  public ILogger Logger{get;set;}
  ... other methods...
}

MVCApp
------

public HomeController : Controller
{
  [Inject]
   public ILogger Logger{get;set;}
  [Inject]
   public IRepository Repository{get;set;}
}
```

I have put all Ninject related code for Di resolution in a separate assembly and that assembly references all other projects.

Here is what happens. When HomeController is instantiated, I have valid instances of Logger and Repository properties. Logger has no dependency, it is perfect. But when I look inside instance of Repository, Logger instance has not been instantiated.

How do you set up DI using Ninject in such situations?

Thanks

Comment: How do you register the `IRepository` and `ILogger` in the `Kernel`?

Comment: Just very basic way to try test this out .. MyKernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<MyLogger>(); MyKernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<MyRepository>()

Comment: This should work. Check if all attributes are there and that everything is public. Also you should do constructor injection.

Comment: @ByteBlocks For purely personal reasons I'd love to see the assembly that does all your binding and how it's referenced and consumed by the UI layer. I've never been able to get that right and no one has been able to explain/show a composite root to me that would work for the kind of NTier systems I build :-) Mine are typically 4 layers sometimes 5 with many many assemblies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by implementing provider for IRepository. In CreateInstance, I instantiated Logger property by resolving it with Kernel.

```
CreateInstance(context)
{
  var repo = new MyRepository();
  repo.Logger = context.Kernel.Get<ILogger>();
}
```

Works like a charm!